# AndroidStudio mouseover warnings - need to Change key stroke for more info

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, warnings aredisplayed when I move my mouse over the relevant bit of code, with instructions to press `ctrl-F1` for more info.

I have ctrl-F1 mapped in the window manager.

Is there a way to change the required key-command in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Keyboard Shortcuts in:

> File -> Settings -> Keymap

There you can search for "Error Description" to change the edit the Keyboard Shortcut.